# How in Joomla create article and open it from the browser by alias?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have created a material assigned him his alias. 
Try to open this page at *mysite.com/myalias* and 404 error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generaly, To access Joomla Contents as : sitename.com/content-alias, you should check below things for your Joomla site:

1. You need to Enable "Search Engine Friendly URLs" from "Global Configuration" section of Joomla Site Administrator.
2. If it still doesn't work, you should create a "Menu Item" in any "Menu" from Joomla Menu Manager from Joomla Site Administrator. But, you must assign this menu item alias same that you want in you

I am sure this will work...

Comment: @user3655719 is it still not working ? Please share here if its not working Or working ? So, others have benefit of your question...